# Effect on Custom Camera in iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, camera, instagram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ios: Adding real time filter effects to photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132333/ios-adding-real-time-filter-effects-to-photos)

I want to apply filter effect to image which is captured by camera. I am successful to apply filter to image before capturing image.

But I want to show that effect live on camera as

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8

and

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/camwow-free-photo-booth-effects/id418368641?mt=8

applications did.

I know in camwow they are using OpenGl for that, but not sure about instagram. Is there any alternative way for applying that effect live on cameraview and also after taking picture to apply to that picture.

If any one knows how can I do that with openGl, I mean any tutorial from where I can start OpenGl so that I can get my requirement as soon as possible

Comment: if you want to actually learn OpenGL, read a couple of books (like the red book); You seem to think this is trivial to make and can be solved with 15 minute tutorial; horrible 'question', do your research on your own. It's on par with "Hey guys, that game looks cool, where's a tutorial to show me how to make one just like it?"

Comment: I just want to know how instagram achieve this functionality using openGl or not. And is there any alternative way to apply that type of effect to custom camera without using OpenGl ? Thanks for your reply @MateuszKowalczyk

Comment: Try this library this may help you:- https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage