# How to add Cartoon Color and Cartoon B&W filter effect on Image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, c, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To Convert Image to Cartoon in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042857/to-convert-image-to-cartoon-in-ios)

I want to add Cartoon Color and Cartoon B&W filter effect on UIImage in iPhone App. can any one suggest how to do this. I search a lot for this and get GPUImage Framework but i dont want to use this whole framework only for a single filter effect.  I can implement if someone suggest its algorithm part.

Thanks

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357403/how-to-cartoon-ify-an-image-programmatically of any interest?  If nothing else, it might give you an idea of the amount of work you're taking on by not reusing existing libraries...

Comment: I m not using GPUImageProcessing because there is a conflict issue of GPUImage and cocoas2d. in my Project I have already cocoas 2d .  so i cant implement toon effect with GPUImage