# Using CIEdgeWork Filters in iOS

Tags: ios, core-image

I am using Core Image filters and trying to make the CIEdgeWork filter. When the filter is applied the image turns black. Am I initializing the CIFilter correctly.

```
 CIFilter *edgeWork = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIEdgeWork"
                                       keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey,filterPreviewImage,
                             @"inputRadius",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0],
                             nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CIEdgeWork is [not available in Core Image on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528726/does-ios-5-support-blur-coreimage-fiters) as of iOS 5.x, so it's no surprise that you're seeing a black image when trying to use it.

However, you can use the GPUImageSketchFilter or GPUImageThresholdEdgeDetection from my [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework to pull off this same effect. You can see the result of the first filter in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830139/where-can-i-find-sample-opengl-es-2-0-shaders-that-perform-image-processing-task/9402041#9402041). The latter filter might be closer to the actual effect that Apple supplies via CIEdgeWork, given that they seem to binarize the resulting edge detected image.

Answer (score 1):

Now CIEdgeWork and CILineOverlay available for iOS9

[CIEdgeWork](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIEdgeWork)

Also you can use CoreImage filter Sobel Sketch, based on GPUImageSketchFilter. 
[FWKSketchFilter](https://gist.github.com/vgoltv/6d1f612573b48a74a434395f67af3ebf)

Kernel of it:

```
kernel vec4 sketch(sampler image, float strength){
vec2 d = destCoord();

vec2 bottomLeftTextureCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, d + vec2(-1.0, -1.0));
vec2 topRightTextureCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, d + vec2(1.0, 1.0));
vec2 topLeftTextureCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, d + vec2(-1.0, 1.0));
vec2 bottomRightTextureCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, d + vec2(1.0, -1.0));

vec2 leftTextureCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, d + vec2(-1.0, 0.0));
vec2 rightTextureCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, d + vec2(1.0, 0.0));
vec2 bottomTextureCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, d + vec2(0.0, -1.0));
vec2 topTextureCoordinate = samplerTransform(image, d + vec2(0.0, 1.0));

float bottomLeftIntensity = sample(image, bottomLeftTextureCoordinate).r;
float topRightIntensity = sample(image, topRightTextureCoordinate).r;
float topLeftIntensity = sample(image, topLeftTextureCoordinate).r;
float bottomRightIntensity = sample(image, bottomRightTextureCoordinate).r;

float leftIntensity = sample(image, leftTextureCoordinate).r;
float rightIntensity = sample(image, rightTextureCoordinate).r;
float bottomIntensity = sample(image, bottomTextureCoordinate).r;
float topIntensity = sample(image, topTextureCoordinate).r;

float h = -topLeftIntensity - 2.0 * topIntensity - topRightIntensity + bottomLeftIntensity + 2.0 * bottomIntensity + bottomRightIntensity;
float v = -bottomLeftIntensity - 2.0 * leftIntensity - topLeftIntensity + bottomRightIntensity + 2.0 * rightIntensity + topRightIntensity;

float mag = 1.0 - (length(vec2(h, v))*strength);

return vec4(vec3(mag), 1.0);}
```

Comment: CIEdgeWork doesnt work on ios11 again, my code was working on ios10 though, `self.firstCIFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIEdgeWork"
                                              withInputParameters:@{@"inputImage":self.firstCIImage,
                                                                    @"inputRadius":@3.00}];`